# Is there a way to limit logging to only print every N times in Julia?

Tags: julia

If I have a `@warn` or `@info` that's logging too much, is there a package or function I can use to limit the warning to only log "every N times" or something like that?

I'm looking for something similar to Google's c++ logging library's function `LOG_EVERY_N(INFO, N)`.
https://github.com/google/glog/blob/195d416e3b1c8dc06980439f6acd3ebd40b6b820/src/glog/logging.h.in#L176

I looked in [Memento.jl](https://github.com/invenia/Memento.jl), [Suppressor.jl](https://github.com/JuliaIO/Suppressor.jl) and Base, but couldn't find anything like this. :)

Comment: It's fairly simple to adapt the `EarlyFilteredLogger` example from LoggingExras to do this https://github.com/oxinabox/LoggingExtras.jl/blob/master/README.md#earlyfilteredlogger

Comment: It's not exactly what you're asking, but ProgressMeter.jl can be set to report at intervals. It can output data values as well as a simple "% done" meter. One of the best ways to see the possibilities is to run the tests in an interactive session.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Memento documentation on handlers. To log at intervals, you can 
do something like:

```
using Memento

mutable struct MyHandler{F<:Formatter, O<:IO} <: Handler{F, O}
    fmt::F
    io::O
    interval::Int
    count::Int
end

c = MyHandler(Memento.DefaultFormatter(), stderr, 10, 0)

function emit(handler::MyHandler{F, O}, rec::Record) where {F<:Formatter, O<:IO}
    if (handler.count += 1) % handler.interval == 0
        str = Memento.format(handler.fmt, rec)
        println(handler.io, str)
        flush(handler.io)
    end
end
```